# Force InetAddress.getHostAddress() to return IPv4 address

Tags: java, ipv6, ipv4

I'm using a library that uses `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` to get my local IP address. However, this always returns an IPv6 address on my computer (Gentoo Linux, JDK 1.6.0_37). The address is further used in a context which does not support IPv6 addresses and thus fails.

Is there some way to force `getHostAddress()` to return a IPv4 address (e.g. through a parameter to JVM)?

Comment: [Get your IP address in java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9482369/1135954) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid changing my source code because the call is within a library which I don't want to change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set it to use IPv4 when avaiable.  Of course, there are a great number more IPv6 address than IPv4 addresses, so it certainly doesn't guarantee always getting an IPv4 address.

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
```

Either set with:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

Or as a command line arg:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Preference for IPv4 addresses is generally default behavior anyway, though.

If you need to ensure that you Never get an IPv6 address, I think you would need to check that `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` does not return an `Inet6Address`, and handle it if it does (as an exception, I suppose).

Either that or, of course, the better way: fix your code to support IPv6.

Comment: What would be the tests to handle exceptions if the address returned is an ipv6 ?