# Android device returns invalid IP address

Tags: android, networking, ip

Hello I am using the code below to get IP address of android device,

```
private String returnIPAdrress()
        {
            String IPAddress = null;
            try
                {
                    for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();)
                        {
                            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();)
                                {
                                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress())
                                        {
                                            IPAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                                        }
                                }
                        }

                }
            catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());
                    return null;
                }
            return IPAddress;
        }
```

When i test it on Galaxy tablet(os=2.3) it works fine and gives me valid IP address.

I have test it on emulator(os=2.2) and it gives me IP address as **10.0.2.15** which is also valid i guess.

But when run it on Micromax canvas(os=4.1) it gives me  IP address as  ***fe80::d0b3:3fff:fe9d:f68c%p2p0*** which is wrong.

is it because of different OS version?

How can i solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282608/force-inetaddress-gethostaddress-to-return-ipv4-address

Comment: Its an IPV6 address. Looks like `JellyBean` uses ipv6 by default.

Comment: @S.D:thanks..i am going to check with other android versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this method:

```
public static String getIPAddress() {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress().toUpperCase();
                    boolean isIPv4 = InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(sAddr);
                    if (isIPv4 && intf.getDisplayName().startsWith("wlan")) {
                        return sAddr;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: +1 for checking if its `ipv4` address but if jellybean supports `ipv6` then i need to deal it with it too.

Comment: This method works on jellybean, it has both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses! If you need the ipv6 address, just remove that isIPv4 check......

Comment: but there is no 1-1 relationship between ipv4 and ipv6;it means that we can convert all ipv4 addresses into ipv6 but not the reverse..

Comment: But this doesn't have anything to do with the original question... you were calling an ipv6 address as "wrong"...

Comment: I apologize,i didn't know that jellybean uses ipv6 when i was posting the question

Comment: And what do you expect to be answered now?

Comment: I test above code with my device with jellybean and it works fine,thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can access IP address of a device using `dhcp.ipaddress`

```
private final WifiManager manager;
private final DhcpInfo dhcp;     
private InetAddress getMyIP() {
    manager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    dhcp = manager.getDhcpInfo();
    final String address = Formatter.formatIpAddress(dhcp.ipAddress); // ipAddress - IP address of my device, assigned through dhcp
    InetAddress myIP = null;

    try {
        myIP = InetAddress.getByName(address);

        Log.i("My IP  "," + myIP.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Cannot find my own IP. Error ", e.toString());
    }

    return myIP;
}
```