# How to get the IP address of a machine in Java

Tags: java, ip-address

Is there a way that I can get the ip address of a machine in Java? To get the IP address from the machine where my jar file is running?

Comment: Did you try asking google for `java get IP address`?

Comment: @home, please see [How should we deal with Google questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the IP address of your machine using the following call:

```
Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

The above is in the Java APIs, so you don't need any jar for that.

Answer (score 5):

The best answer is:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
```

(The `getLocalHost` method is declared in `InetAddress` not `Inet4Address`.)

It is also worth nothing that `getLocalHost()` does some security checks, so this may not work if your JAR is run in a sandbox.

Comment: I liked it more when @Dan said it.

Comment: ...or when Stephen said it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-our-own-system-using-java/9482369#9482369) :-)

Comment: @CameronFredman - I could have simply commented on Dan's answer ... but I decided that what I had to add was worth a new one.

Comment: @StephenC My apologies.  I was reading that on my phone and didn't catch the InetAddress/Inet4Address distinction.