# Need specific IP address of machines on network

Tags: java, networking

My code needs to insert ip address of the machine it is running upon. I am doing this by,

```
InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
String hostAddress = IP.getHostAddress().trim();
//insert ip into DB
```

Now my client rightly informed me that when tested this code on different machines, all inserted ip as 127.0.0.1. I undertand that machines are network and thus returning local host ip.

but how to resolve this? I need uniq ip address of individual box.

Comment: Check this question out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-our-own-system-using-java

Comment: Note that a computer can have more than one IP address (e.g., wireless card and wired card). Also note that IP addresses may not be unique (e.g. 192.168.0.x).

Comment: Are the computers properly connected to a network?