# how to get the client's IP?

Tags: java, ip

My code always return the loopback ip instead of my IP whick is 192.168.*.*

```
try {

            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());
          } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          }
```

Comment: can you explain *My code always return the loopback*

Comment: maybe this post can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-java

Comment: He is getting the loopback (internal) IP address of the computer on the private network, not the public IP address.  But this question is a duplicate.

Comment: im getting 127.0.1.1 always

Answer (score 0):

There are some websites, that their sole piece of data is one line, which includes your *public* IP address.

Try something like:

```
URLConnection con = new URL("http://www.myipaddress.com").openConnection();
String ip = new BufferedReader(new 
                    InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())).readLine();
```

Comment: OP wants to do using java,so he has posted java code,I think you should give an answer in java

Comment: @SpringLearner Hope that helps.

Comment: I think your code wont compile

Comment: you can compile and run

Comment: HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
         String ip = httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
         System.out.println(ip);

Comment: got it with the above code