# Find a automatic server ip when running server.java

Tags: java, ip, client, server

I created server client app in eclipse. I block firewall and running perfectly. I run `server.java` and `client.java` in different computers.There is no problem. I have hardcoded server's ip in `client.java` (for e.g.: 10.10.154.10).

I have a question for server's ip. `client.java` running in another computer. From `server.java`  how can I find server ip automatically?

**Server.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.Iterator;

public class Server extends JFrame {


    private ServerSocket serverSock;
    private int port;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server();
    }

    public Server() {
        // Place text area on the frame
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        port = 1453;
        try {
            InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String adres = inet.getHostAddress();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JLabel("Server Address:"));
            txtAdres = new JTextField(7);
            panel.add(txtAdres);
            txtAdres.setText(adres);
            txtAdres.setEditable(false);
            panel.add(new JLabel("Port:"));
            txtPort = new JTextField(5);
            panel.add(txtPort);
            txtPort.setText(String.valueOf(port));

            panel.add(btnStart);
            panel.add(btnStop);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);
            add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        btnActionStartClass actionStart = new btnActionStartClass();
        btnActionStopClass actionStop = new btnActionStopClass();

        btnStart.addActionListener(actionStart);
        btnStop.addActionListener(actionStop);

        setTitle("Server");
        setSize(500, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true); // It is necessary to show the frame here!
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    }// end of contructor

     class btnActionStartClass implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnStart.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);

            Thread starter = new Thread(new ServerStarter());
            starter.start();
            jta.append("Server started at " + new Date()+"\n");

        }

    }//end of actionstartclass
     class btnActionStopClass implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            btnStart.setEnabled(true);
            btnStop.setEnabled(false);

            try {
                serverSock.close();
                jta.append("Server is closed. \n");
                messageToClients("Server is closed..");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }//end of actionstopclass


     class ServerStarter implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            broadcast = new ArrayList();

            try{
                port = Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText().trim());
                serverSock = new ServerSocket(port);

                while(true){
                    Socket socket = serverSock.accept();
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    broadcast.add(writer);

                    Thread listener = new Thread(new ThreadClient(socket, writer));
                    listener.start();
                    jta.append("Connection Success!\n");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                jta.append("Error making a connection. \n");
            }

        }

    }//end ServerStarter

    class ThreadClient implements Runnable {

        private Socket socket;
        private PrintWriter writer;
        BufferedReader reader;
        public ThreadClient(Socket socket, PrintWriter writer) {

            this.writer = writer;

            try{
                this.socket = socket;
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                jta.append("Unexpected error.. \n");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String message;
            String[] arr;

            try{
                while((message = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                    //jta.append("Received: "+ message + "\n");
                    arr = message.split(":");

                    if(arr[2].equals("Connect")){
                        messageToClients((arr[0] + ":" + arr[1] + ":" + "Chat"));
                    }
                    else if (arr[2].equals("Chat")) 
                        {
                        messageToClients(message);
                        } 
                   else 
                        {
                        jta.append("No Conditions were met. \n");
                        }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                jta.append("Lost a connection. \n");
                 ex.printStackTrace();
                 broadcast.remove(socket);
            }
        }//end-RUN

    }//end-ThreadClient

    public void messageToClients(String message){

        java.util.Iterator iter = broadcast.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){

            try{
                PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter)iter.next();
                writer.println(message);
                //jta.append("Sending: "+ message+ "\n");
                writer.flush();
                jta.setCaretPosition(jta.getDocument().getLength());

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                jta.append("Error telling everyone. \n");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
public class Client extends JFrame {

        tfAddress.setText("localhost");
        tfPort.setText("1453");
        //////////////Panel TOP
        panelTop.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panelTop.add(lbl1);
        panelTop.add(tfAddress);
        panelTop.add(lbl2);
        panelTop.add(tfPort);
        panelTop.add(btnLogin);

        add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //////////////Panel CENTER
        jta.setEditable(false);
        add(jta, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //////////////Panel BOTTOM
        panelBottom.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tfInput = new JTextField(30);
        btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        panelBottom.add(tfInput);
        panelBottom.add(btnSend);

        add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        loginActionClass loginAction = new loginActionClass();
        sendActionClass sendAction = new sendActionClass();

        btnLogin.addActionListener(loginAction);

        tfInput.addActionListener(sendAction);
        btnSend.addActionListener(sendAction);




    }//end-of-constructor


    public class threadReaderClass implements Runnable
    {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String[] data;
            String coming;
            String connect = "Connect";
            String chat = "Chat";

            try{
                while((coming = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    data = coming.split(":");
                    if(data[2].equals("Chat"))
                    {
                        jta.append(data[0] + ":" + data[1]  + "\n");
                        jta.setCaretPosition(jta.getDocument().getLength());
                    }


                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

    }//end-threadReaderClass

    public class loginActionClass implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(isConnected == false ){

                String anonymous = "anonymous";
                String value = String.valueOf((new Random().nextInt(999) +1));
                anonymous = anonymous.concat(value);

                username = anonymous;

                try {
                    address = tfAddress.getText().trim();
                    port = Integer.parseInt(tfPort.getText().trim());

                    socket = new Socket(address, port);

                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

                    writer.println(username + ":has connected.:Connect");
                    writer.flush();

                    isConnected = true;
                } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                    jta.append("Cannot connect :/ please try again \n" );
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                //go! for open thread for incoming..!
                Thread threadReaderClass = new Thread(new threadReaderClass());
                threadReaderClass.start();
                /////////////////////////////////////

            }//end-if
            else if(isConnected == true){
                jta.append("You are already connected. \n");
            }

        }

    }

    public class sendActionClass implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if((tfInput.getText()).equals("")){

                tfInput.setText("");
                tfInput.requestFocus();
            }
            else
            {
                try{
                    writer.println(username + ":" + tfInput.getText() + ":" + "Chat");
                    writer.flush();
                }catch(Exception de){
                    jta.append("message dont go --> --> --\\>");
                }

                tfInput.setText("");
                tfInput.requestFocus();
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        Client frame = new Client();
        frame.setTitle("Client");
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you show is not relevant to the IP stack. If the server has a known name, then you can perhaps look via dns for it's IP. Otherwise there are no magical ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I see this options:

- In a limited range of ip addresses (subnet ?) and port numbers you could do some probing. Since you have to wait for timeouts, this will not be fast.
- Have some kind of registery for clients and server(s)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look about this topic :

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-java)

It describes how to get all network address on a computer. There is no magic, you'll have to parse/process the output of the example. Don't forget to take care to differenciate addresses, private or others !