# Get IP that the server is running on

Tags: java, ip-address, bukkit

I'm trying to get the IP of my server.
I couldn't use `Bukkit.getServer().getIp()` because I would need to set `server-ip=` in the *server.properties* file.

Comment: I don't know Bukkit at all, but if it runs with JRE in a JVM try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java:

```
InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("IP: " + IP.getHostAddress());
```

Another way if you're using Servlet:

```
request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's mistaken: The method to get the server's IP is `ServletRequest.getLocalAddr()`: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalAddr%28%29