# Update text from class that extends Task

Tags: java, javafx

The following JavaFx program is supposed to get the current IP address on the machine once a button is pressed and show it on the screen. I have gotten everything to work, but I am having issues updating the text from the class that extends Task

MainApp.java

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

        stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        stage.setTitle("IP Viewer");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

my FXMLController

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

        Task<Void> task = new IpTask();;

        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

IpTask: It gets the current IP address and tried to update the UI, but I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception on `textIp.setText`

```
public class IpTask extends Task<Void> {

    @FXML
    private Text textIp;

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        Common common = new Common();
        Ip ip = common.getIp();
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed() {
        System.out.println("Failed!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        System.out.println("Updated");  
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textIp.setText("JUST TO SEE IF THE TEXT GETS SET");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and below is my Scene.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.limitedenterprisesinc.ipviewer.FXMLController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
        <!-- <Label layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" fx:id="label" /> -->
        <javafx.scene.text.Text layoutX="126" layoutY="140" fx:id="textIp"/>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

How can I update the textIp textfield from the IpTask class?

Comment: why do you use Thread, it's just get ip , you don't need them!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields are injected to the controller instance that is used with the `FXMLLoader`. `IpTask` is not used as a controller and therefore nothing is injected to the field.

Inject the field to the controller and pass it to `IpTask`. Furthermore you don't have to use `Platform.runLater` in the `succeeded` method, since it's invoked on the JavaFX application thread.

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Text textIp;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Task<Void> task = new IpTask(textIp);

        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    ...
}
```

```
public class IpTask extends Task<Void> {

    private final Text textIp;

    public IpTask(Text textIp) {
        if (textIp == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.textIp = textIp;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        System.out.println("Updated");
        textIp.setText("JUST TO SEE IF THE TEXT GETS SET");
    }
}
```