# Java get the hostname and other env var through jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, environment-variables

I'm using jenkins to build my projects and i can't get the hostname with java

According to this [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) I wrote the follow lines

```
            System.out.println(System.getenv("MACHINE"));
            System.out.println(System.getenv("HOSTNAME"));
```

These are environment variables. BUt the output on build is:

```
 null
 null
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where is this code located, where you want to know the hostname? Is this in a jenkins plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem using the [Jenkins Enviromenment Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin)

Wiht this plugin I can just run a shell script code and save the values as var to use in the build.

```
host=$(hostname)
flavor=$(cat /etc/os-release |grep ^'NAME=' |cut -d'=' -f2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Jenkins script console, you can try:

```
println InetAddress.getLocalHost()
```

There is some very good discussion on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-java).

Comment: Thanks but i need to get anotther's env var too, with this i get only localhost hostname.