# Socket.getLocalAddress() returning loopback address on windows

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to get hostname of my windows server using below code:

```
Socket.getLocalAddress().getCanonicalHostName();
```

It's returning the loopback address. in Java help for `getLocalAddress()` it is mentioned as

> "If there is a security manager set, its checkConnect method is called
>   with the local address and -1 as its arguments to see if the operation
>   is allowed. If the operation is not allowed, the loopback address is
>   returned"

Could anyone tell what is this security manager exactly? how I will get the Exact IP address instead of loopback address?

Comment: What did you connect the socket to before you called `getLocalAddress()`?

Comment: using 'SocketFetcher.getSocket()'

Answer (score 1):

`InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` should give you the IP address.

This is from java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html).

> > A security manager is an object that defines a security policy for an application. This policy specifies actions that are unsafe or sensitive. Any actions not allowed by the security policy cause a SecurityException to be thrown. An application can also query its security manager to discover which actions are allowed.

For further information check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-java) SO post.

Comment: For further information check the answer you linked  which says almost exactly the opposite of what you claim here.

Comment: @EJP accepted answer has detail info like how to handle when there are multiple network interface, etc. but others answer kind of straight forward.