# How to get the IP address of the present OS rather than a virtual OS

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, ip

I need to find the ip address of computer.But i want the IP address of the network,only if connected.The code i used is:

```
inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
String ipadd=inet.getHostAddress();
```

But I have vmware in my laptop and this code return ip from it.It returns an ip even when i'm not connected to a network and the ip is not 127.0.0.1 .So i checked the interface,it's coming from the vmware.I need it to stop doing that...Please help me out.I really need to finish this soon.
Any and all comments will be appreciated :)

Comment: From your programs view, the virtual machine is the real machine. You should not be able to go outside of the sandbox it provides.

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38342964/1098063