# Get public ip address in spring security application managed by docker swarm

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-security, docker-swarm

My spring boot application is running in a docker environment. It is managed by docker swarm. 
I am trying to restrict some of the api to certain apis but the spring security is receiving private ip address instead of public.

I want the application to recieve the public address for the request so that I can use spring security to restrict access apis to certain apis.

If this is not possbile is there another solution to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-java

Comment: @pvpkiran This is not related.. I want the ip address of the user and the the server..

Comment: as you can see from the answer, it is not possible to get exact ipaddress. That was the point of that post. Check the answer from stephen C in that post