# Integrating WinAppDriver and Selenium

Tags: java, remote-debugging, winappdriver

I am using both Selenium, testng and WinAppDriver with Java via Eclipse (and ultimately Jenkins) and IE (via Edge IE compatibility).  I use Selenium the normal way, and when I hit a certain page (which requires a windows box login and password) I start up WinAppDriver to fill in the boxes.  This works fine when running locally on my Eclipse machine.

I start up WinAppDriver and do a connect to

```
 exec = new HttpCommandExecutor(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/"));
```

As I said though this will ultimately be on the Jenkins grid.  To simulate this from eclipse we can set

```
 com.xxxxx.test.driver=remote
 com.xxxxx.test.hub=http://seleniumhub:4444/wd/hub
```

This runs, I believe, the software on a master VM and the browser on one of many slave VMs.

So while running remotely as shown above I got an error message that it could not find an element ("user Name").  I then thought it must be because I had to run WinAppDriver on all the VMs.  So I ran it, but still got the same error.

It occurs to me I shouldn't use 127.0.0.1:4723 as I will be debugging on a remote browser.  So I thought I should replace the IP address with the machine that the browser is running on (which will also be running WinAppDriver).  Since there are many slave VMs I can't hardcode an IP address.  I am trying to figure out a way to find the IP of the slave VM the browser is running on, from my Java program.  I want to try that in the connection string to WinAppDriver.

any suggestions?

Comment: Local IP you can get by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-java

But: You wrote the service under test is every times in master. So the service IP for me sounds constant under a fixed name. (DNS)

To use the local IP address is for sure not correct, if testing software using selenium is browsing to a service on another host.

The error message "could not find an element ..." means that your selenium browser gets an unexpected result. => Wrong host?